# Word interop, table border

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I'll try say what i want:
I create a word doc, and add a table, fine, but the border of table are transparent and i cant work with it, i need to write at doc to save as PDF.

I have a nice class that control word, but with table i lost my mind i didnt solve the problem.

I using winform with .net 3.5

```
    // atributos - atributes 
    public static object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; // Valores defauls que não precisa alterar
    public static Word.Application w_app; // aplicação do word
    public static Word.Document w_doc; // documento do word

    // metodos - methods
    public void criar_novo_arquivo_word() // create a new file word doc
    {
        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        w_app = app;
        w_doc = app.Documents.Add(missing, missing, missing, missing);
        w_app.Visible = false;
    }

    public void visualizar_word(bool opcao) // set visible
    {
        w_app.Visible = opcao;
    }

    public void inserir_tabela(int numero_de_linhas, int numero_de_colunas) // insert table, here live my problema
    {
        Word.Range range = w_doc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
        range.Tables.Add(range, numero_de_linhas, numero_de_colunas);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void inserir_tabela(int numero_de_linhas, int numero_de_colunas) // insert table, here live my problema
{
    Word.Range range = w_doc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
    Word.Table myTable = range.Tables.Add(range, numero_de_linhas, numero_de_colunas);

    myTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
    myTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
}
```